# writing in excel from access line by line using vba code

Tags: excel, vba

Hi guys i am new here and i am new to vba.

i want to solve the following problem:

i have two different access tables. each of them contains data i want to compare first and then, if a certain constraint is true i want to import certain columns out of one of the two access db tables into an excel sheet.

what i already have: the connection to the databases, i can read the data and print them on the console via debug.print command.

i have really no idea how to write certain rows (those which conform to the constraint) to the excel sheet.

### *Code sample*

```
'commandstring and data base variables stands here

'non database connection variables

Dim oldID, newID, oldBuildPlanned, newBuildPlanned As String
Dim createExcel, doesExcelExist As Boolean
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim Wksht As Excel.Worksheet
Dim dataVar As String
Dim counter As Integer

counter = 0
createExcelSheet = False
doesSheetExist = False

'Debug.Print "TEST old database"
Do While Not objRs.EOF And Not objRs2.EOF
    'Debug.Print vbTab & objRs(0) & " " & objRs(1)

    'assigning database values to variables to make them comparable
    oldID = objRs(counter)
    newID = CStr(objRs2(counter))
    oldBuildPlanned = objRs(counter + 1)
    newBuildPlanned = objRs2(counter + 1)

If oldID = newID And oldBuildPlanned = newBuildPlanned Then

  createExcel = True

    If createExcelSheet = True And Not doesSheetExist = True Then

    Set xl = New Excel.Application


    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add

    Set Wksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    doesExcelExist = True

    End If        

Call writeReport(newID)

End If

    objRs.MoveNext
    objRs2.MoveNext
Loop

'tidy up stuff comes here
```

### *end of code*

I am sorry if my code is not formatted as its usual, its my first post in this forum ^^

So the writeReport() should contain the code to write the data into the sheet. i planned to insert the id's of the matching database entries into the method as parameters and read these certain data out of the recordset. but i cannot convert recordset items to string, so the byRef parameter declaration causes a compile error "type mismatch". In addition i tried to export the table with DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, but this method exports the entire table into excel, it worked, but it is not what i am searching for.

i hope someone can help me with my little low level problem, if you need further information feel free to ask me. i am using ADO.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Welcome to the forum,

I think you might find these two websites helpful for what you are trying to do. The first one is a great tutorial on using Access and Excel together.

http://www.datawright.com.au/excel_resources/excel_access_and_ado.htm

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

I am not sure how you are creating your recordset, by I would recommend using an SQL statement as your source. That way you only pull the data from Access that you need. If you have any more specific questions, please let me know.

Jason